# Which columns are used in kmeans algorithm in R, as there are no arguments for designating columns?

Tags: r, k-means, rxkmeans

Says, a dataframe `df_1` has 8 columns, and following code is used.

```
res = kmeans(df_1, 4, nstart=40)
```

The K-means clustering result is stored in `res`.

In most examples, two dimensions (i.e. two columns) are used to demonstrate the clustering.

However, in the above code, `df_1` has 8 dimensions.

How do I know, which columns were used?

Comment: have u checked the cheat sheet ?

Comment: @sai sara, I did not check any sheet. I just did some research online and no example showed the criteria of the input data.frame.

Comment: ?kmeans can u try this one

Comment: Description

Perform k-means clustering on a data matrix.

Usage

kmeans(x, centers, iter.max = 10, nstart = 1,
       algorithm = c("Hartigan-Wong", "Lloyd", "Forgy",
                     "MacQueen"), trace=FALSE)
## S3 method for class 'kmeans'
fitted(object, method = c("centers", "classes"), ...)

Comment: They will all be used. If you want to use only certain columns then limit the columns in the data frame that you pass to the kmeans function